# How can I convert this Function to list comprehension in python?

Tags: python

```
def extract_and_apply(l, p, f):
    result = []
    for x in l:
        if p(x):
            result.append(f(x))
    return result
```

I'm new to python and I have to convert this function to a list comprehension, which I can't figure out. A little help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hey there, Theres plenty of examples of how to handle comprehension for many situations in there, along with many other questions already posted on SO if you search the topic *list comprehnsion*

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions use the same order as nested loops.

```
for a in blist:
     for c in dlist:
           if c in elist:
               result.append((a, c))
```

Can be written as:

```
result = [(a,c) for a in blist for c in dlist if c in elist]
```

Note: It's the same word order. When it gets confusing I just write out the nested loop and the delete the line breaks and colons.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [f(x) for x in l if p(x)]
```

You can write if statements inside the list comprehension